# find the probability that exist 1 person that all of his friends are in the other group.(split 6 persons in two groups?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

6 students in a class are randomly and independently split to 2 groups.

A group can be empty.

All students has a least 1 friend.

The total number of friendships is 10.

Find the probability that exist one student that all of his friends are in the other group.

The number of ways to split is:32.

$\frac{ \binom{6}{0}+ \binom{6}{1} + \binom{6}{2}+ \binom{6}{3}+ \binom{6}{4} + \binom{6}{5}+ \binom{6}{6}}{2} = \frac{64}{2} = 32$
,that is the sample space.

How can I solve it?

I tried to find the complementary event but I don't progress with it...